# execute printf command shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am a beginner in writing shell script (probably my 1st shell script).
I have a shell script that I like to run. The command is a simple grep command based on the parameter passed to it. I managed to get the correct grep command using the script below.

```
FILE='testurls'
MERCHANT_ID='8'
printf "grep '^%s' %s\n" "$MERCHANT_ID" "$FILE"

./hello.sh 
grep '^8' testurls
```

How would I execute the command instead of printing it.

Comment: Aside: By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
                variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is not necessary

```
FILE='testurls'
MERCHANT_ID='8'
grep "^$MERCHANT_ID" "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use shell backticks quotes. This will store the output of executable commands.

Syntax are :-

1) Legacy Bourne shell backticks ``:

```
var=`grep "^$MERCHANT_ID" "$FILE"` 
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

2) $() syntax:

```
var=$(grep "^$MERCHANT_ID" "$FILE")
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```